# iOS7 / Mavericks apps icloud coredata slow first sync

Tags: ios, core-data, ios7, icloud, osx-mavericks

I have released in appstore an app with iOS7 version and Mavericks OSX version. iCloud + coredata.

- The objects I add with the iOS version takes 3 or 4 seconds to be visible in Mavericks version.
- The objects I add with the Mavericks version takes various minutes to be replicated to iOS version (without entering in background, I force the iOS app to be in foreground).

**NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification** takes some minutes before first invocation in iOS. Why? Is someone experimenting the same trouble? Thanks

Comment: Same thing for me. Just basically tell your user to be patient is all I can think of

Comment: Take a look at this link, near the bottom is a link to an OS X / iOS integration using Core Data and iCloud page which includes a video showing the apps in action.  The times you see there seem to be typical, you can see quite clearly in one section the almost immediate download by OS X whereas on iOS you have to open the file to trigger a download. http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/uimanageddocument-icloud-integration/

Comment: There is also a section showing how to disable the UI until the store has switched to the iCloud store and downloaded initial data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely this is because iOS and Mac OS X handle iCloud updates differently.

- Mac OS X is "greedy". As soon as an iCloud update exists, Mac OS X starts downloading it. Even if the app isn't running. Even if the app isn't installed on the Mac. Even if the app doesn't run on Macs. (Macs download iCloud data for iOS-only apps).
- iOS doesn't download anything from iCloud until it receives a request from an app.

This means that the Mac app gets a head start. When the Mac app asks for the data, there's a good chance it's already there. And if it's not all there, it's probably already downloading. But on iOS the process doesn't even start until you request it.

There might be other factors at play, but Mac OS X is always going to get a head start over iOS for iCloud updates.

Comment: Thanks Tom. This means that there is no remedy?

Comment: None that I know of, besides general stuff like not syncing more data than you really need to sync. The less data, the less time, so reducing that may help if there's a way.

Comment: I have marked your response as accepted but it means to assume that icloud still isn't functionally nowadays. A calendar app have to sync all data and users can't wait 2 minutes to view their events... Very bad news for iCloud developers I think...

Comment: Sure it's functional, it just functions differently on different devices. iOS devices typically have much less storage space and slower and less reliable network connections, so Mac style downloading is not a good idea.